# django-grpc-framework: correct way to serialize/deserialize JSONFields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

what is the proper way to handle *Django* **JSONFields** in the **django-grpc-framework** ?
How can I check, what kind of data is actually sent ([Evans](https://github.com/ktr0731/evans) throw the same error) =

When I try to receive a serialized **JSONFiled** with the [django-grpc-framework](https://github.com/fengsp/django-grpc-framework),

the following error is thrown in my data_grpc_client.py:

> > python data_grpc_client.py  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/my_data/data_grpc_client.py", line 8, in 
> > for datum in stub.List(my_data.lara_data_pb2.DataListRequest()):   File ".../python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 426, in
> > **next**
> > return self._next()   File .../lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _next
> > raise self grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:     status =
> > StatusCode.UNKNOWN    details = "Exception iterating responses: Failed
> > to parse data_JSON field: expected string or bytes-like object."
> > debug_error_string =
> > "{"created":"@1648155177.535827174","description":"Error received from
> > peer
> > ipv6:[::1]:50051","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":905,"grpc_message":"Exception
> > iterating responses: Failed to parse data_JSON field: expected string
> > or bytes-like object.","grpc_status":2}"

I would be very happy for any help - thanks a lot in advance !
Elain

Here are my python/proto modules - to reproduce the error:

I have a django (4.0.3) model with a JSON field:

```
# models.py

class Data(models.Model):
  data_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  data_JSON = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="JSON representation of the data")
```

My serializer.py looks like this:

```
from  my_data.models import Data
from django_grpc_framework import proto_serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
import my_data.my_data_pb2


class DataProtoSerializer(proto_serializers.ModelProtoSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        proto_class = my_data.my_data_pb2.Data
        fields = ['data_id', 'data_JSON']
```

The auto generated protofile file (I used the django framework proto generator)  my_data.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my_data;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service DataController {
    rpc List(DataListRequest) returns (stream Data) {}
    rpc Create(Data) returns (Data) {}
    rpc Retrieve(DataRetrieveRequest) returns (Data) {}
    rpc Update(Data) returns (Data) {}
    rpc Destroy(Data) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

message Data {
    int32 data_id = 1;
    string data_JSON = 2;
}

message DataListRequest {
}

message DataRetrieveRequest {
    int32 data_id = 1;
}
```

My service description - services.py :

```
from my_data.models import Data
from django_grpc_framework import generics
from my_data.serializers import DataProtoSerializer


class DataService(generics.ModelService):
    """
    gRPC service that allows users to be retrieved or updated.
    """
    queryset = Data.objects.all().order_by('data_id') 
    serializer_class = DataProtoSerializer
```

And finally the client: data_grpc_client.py:

```
import grpc
import my_data.my_data_pb2
import my_data.my_data_pb2_grpc


with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel:
    stub = my_data.my_data_pb2_grpc.DataControllerStub(channel)
    for datum in stub.List(my_data.my_data_pb2.DataRequest()):
        print("datum:",datum.name, end='')
```

Comment: I didn't use JSON field in Django grpc framework, but in protobuf assume string type for this field and it is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad, I can see this in the error message - but how do I find out, what the expected type is ? Btw. this part of the serialisation / deserialisation should work out of the box as with simple types (strings / ints / bools are just transferred fine ).

Comment: You can use map but it isn’t handy for nested json. I convert json to string and use load and dump to archive the json.